# Why does this happen when a user-defined R function does not return a value?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-plotly

In the function shown below, there is no `return`. However, after executing it, I can confirm that the value entered `d` normally.

There is no `return`. Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

**Code**

```
#installed plotly, dplyr
accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
  cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}


d <- txhousing %>%
  filter(year > 2005, city %in% c("Abilene", "Bay Area")) %>%
  accumulate_by(~date)
```

Comment: YOu are returning `bind_rows(dats)`

Comment: `return` is only required explicitly when you want the function to exit and return something before the end of the function definition. Otherwise, the last command executed in the function is implicitly `return`ed.

Answer (score 3):

In the function, the last assignment is creating 'dats' which is returned with `bind_rows(dats)`  We don't  need an explicit `return` statement.  Suppose, if there are two objects to be returned, we can place it in a `list`

---

In some languages like `python`, for memory efficiency, `generators` are used which will `yield` instead of creating the whole output in memory i.e.  Consider two functions in `python`

```
def get_square(n):
    result = []
    for x in range(n):
        result.append(x**2)
return result
```

When we run it

```
get_square(4)
#[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

The same function can be written as a `generator`.  Instead of `return`ing anything,

```
def get_square(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield(x**2)
```

Running the function

```
get_square(4) 
#<generator object get_square at 0x0000015240C2F9E8>
```

By casting with `list`, we get the same output

```
list(get_square(4))
#[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is always a return :) You just don't have to be explicit about it.

*All* R expressions return something. Including control structures and user-defined functions. (Control-structures are just functions, by the way, so you can just remember that everything is a value or a function call, and everything evaluates to a value).

For functions, the return value is the last expression evaluated in the execution of the function. So, for

```
f <- function(x) 2 + x
```

when you call `f(3)` you will invoke the function `+` with two parameters, `2` and `x`. These evaluate to `2` and `3`, respectively, so `` `+`(2, 3) `` evaluates to `5`, and that is the result of `f(3)`.

When you call the `return` function -- and remember, this is a function -- you just leave the control-flow of a function early. So,

```
f <- function(x) {
    if (x < 0) return(0)
    x + 2
}
```

works as follows: When you call `f`, it will call the `if` function to figure out what to do in the first statement. The `if` function will evaluate `x < 0` (which means calling the function `<` with parameters `x` and `0`). If `x < 0` is true, `if` will evaluate `return(0)`. If it is false, it will evaluate its `else` part (which, because `if` has a special syntax when it comes to functions, isn't shown, but is `NULL`). If `x < 0` is not true, `f` will evaluate `x + 2` and return that. If `x < 0` *is* true, however, the `if` function will evaluate `return(0)`. This is a call to the function `return`, with parameter `0`, and that call will terminate the execution of `f` and make the result `0`.

Be careful with `return`. It is a function so

```
f <- function(x) {
    if (x < 0) return;
    x + 2
}
```

is perfectly valid R code, but it will not return when `x < 0`. The `if` call will just evaluate to the function `return` but not call it.

The `return` function is also a little special in that it can return from the parent call of control structures. Strictly speaking, `return` isn't evaluated in the frame of `f` in the examples above, but from inside the `if` calls. It just handles this special so it *can* return from `f`.

With non-standard evaluation this isn't *always* the case.

With this function

```
f <- function(df) {
    with(df, if (any(x < 0)) return("foo") else return("bar"))
    "baz"
}
```

you might think that

```
f(data.frame(x = rnorm(10)))
```

should return either `"foo"` or `"bar"`. After all, we return in either case in the `if` statement. However, the `if` statement is evaluated inside `with` and it doesn't work that way. The function will return `baz`.

For non-local returns like that, you need to use `callCC`, and then it gets more technical (as if this wasn't technical enough).

If you can, try to avoid `return` completely and rely on functions returning the last expression they evaluate.

### Update

Just to follow up on the comment below about loops. When you call a loop, you will most likely call one of the built-in primitive functions. And, yes, they return `NULL`. But you can write your own, and they will follow the rule that they return the last expression they evaluate. You can, for example, implement `for` in terms of `while` like this:

```
`for` <- function(itr_var, seq, body) {
    itr_var <- as.character(substitute(itr_var))
    body <- substitute(body)
    e <- parent.frame()
    j <- 1
    while (j < length(seq)) {
        assign(x = itr_var, value = seq[[j]], envir = e)
        eval(body, envir = e)
        j <- j + 1
    }
    "foo"
}
```

This function, will definitely return `"foo"`, so this

```
for(i in 1:5) { print(i) }
```

evalutes to `"foo"`. If you want it to return `NULL`, you have to be explicit about it (or just let the return value be the result of the `while` loop -- if that is the primitive `while` it returns `NULL`).

The point I want to make is that functions return the last expression they evaluate has to do with how the functions are *defined*, not how you call them. The loops use non-standard evaluation, so the last expression in the loop body you provide them *might* be the last value they evaluate and might not. For the primitive loops, it is not.

Except for their special syntax, there is nothing magical about loops. They follow the rules all functions follow. With non-standard evaluation it can get a bit tricky to work out from a function call what the last expression they will evaluate might be, because the function body looks like it is what the function evaluates. It is, to a degree, if the function is sensible, but the loop body is *not* the function body. It is a parameter. If it wasn't for the special syntax, and you had to provide loop bodies as normal parameters, there might be less confusion.

Comment: `for` loops return NULL.

Comment: Yes. Looks return `NULL`. Both `for`, `while` and `repeat`. However, `NULL` is also *something`* so I stand by my claim that all functions return *something* ;) If you wrote your own `for` loop -- which, of course, you easily can by assigning a function to `` `for` ``, then you would have to be explicit about returning `NULL`.

Comment: Yes. I do understand that NULL is something. It is, however, not the value of the last expression encountered when inside the function.

Comment: I disagree. The `.Primitive("foo")` returns `NULL`, but if you wrote your own `for` it would return the last expression it evaluated. So, while the primitive functions do not exactly have to follow the rules that pure R functions do, it is easier to think about it that way, and should you implement your own control structures, they will definitely behave as I explained.

Comment: You are free to disagree,  but an ordinary R `for` function does NOT have a "return value [that] is the last expression evaluated in the execution of the function".  And if a `for`-loop is the last expression evaluated inside a function, then that function will return a NULL, regardless of the body of the loop. I'm just trying to prevent newcomers to R from falling into a common source of unexpected behavior.

Comment: A loop body is just not the same as a function body, is my point. If you wrote `f(x, y, z)` you wouldn't expect `f` to return `z`. It would return whatever was the last expression evaluated in `f`. If you assign `` f <- `for` `` it is exactly the same thing. It is a simple rule for what functions return -- the last expression evaluated -- and loops are not an exception. Their syntax is different, but `f(x, y, { a <- 1 ; b <- 2 ; a + b})` is no different from `for (x in y) { a <- 1 ; b <- 2 ; a + b }`. The return value depends on the *body* of `f` (or `for`); the loop-body is just an argument.

Comment: Interesting perspective, but I believe it is incorrect. The body of a for-loop is evaluated, whereas the items in the argument list are not evaluated. They are passed as promises.

Comment: Here's a counter-example to your perspective: `testfun <- function(x) { x <- 4; for(i in 1:3){x <- x+1; cat(x)} };
; z <- testfun(4)
; z`  #returns
NULL. The last assignment evaluated in that function is actually 7 as can be seen at the console, but because the `for` loop is last and x is not evaluated outside the loop, its value does not get returned.

Comment: I don't know if comments here is the right place to discuss this. I'm not sufficiently familiar with SO to know if it makes sense to make a separate "question" for this?

Comment: In any case, your "counterexample" isn't one. The last expression in your function is not `cat(x)` but the whole `for` expression. Same as the last expression in `function(x) f(x)` is `f(x)` and not `x`. The body of `for` is as much a promise as any other arguments. It is just evaluated in the implementation. By default the `do_for` function in C, but you can change that, of course, and `for <- function(itrvar, seq, bd) { 42 } ;
for (i in stop("not evaluated")) stop("not evaluated either")` will run just fine. (Put for in backticks here; the comment formatting won't allow me, though).

Comment: The *only* thing that makes `for` loops special is the syntactic sugar. Other than that, they are just functions and live by the same rules as other functions. They are implemented in C (function do_for in eval.c if you are interested) but so are many other functions. The so-called primitive functions.

Comment: Well, perhaps we don't really disagree then. The `for` function returns NULL. Newcomers to R need to know that.

Comment: We never disagreed that the default `for` (and `while` and `repeat`) implementation(s) return `NULL`. My point was just that the rule for *all*( functions is that they return the last evaluated expression; for the loops that is just explicitly made to be `NULL` in the implementation of those functions. Sorry for being unclear.